# To INCLUDE or Not INCLUDE in an Index

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, index-tuning, nonclustered-index

### Current Situation

I am observing a simple statement that is querying one table and accessing multiple indexes to retrieve the data:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
feld16,
zahl4,
feld12,
feld19 FROM 
object1 WHERE 
(deleted = 0 or deleted IS NULL)
```

The query execution plan can be found on [Brent Ozar's Paste The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HyN9i7hKs) website and a graphical representation follows:

[image: Query Execution Plan for above SELECT statement]

The table is made up of 82 columns containing various data. The distribution of the data in the `deleted` column is:

```
 deleted | Number of records
---------+-------------------
       0 |        71'620'068
    NULL |                10
 a value |            59'673
```

The result set contains approx. 64 million rows of the approx. 71 million rows that match the search predicate `WHERE (deleted = 0 or deleted IS NULL)`. This is because the `DISTINCT` omits 7 million records.

### Going Forward

In order to speed things up a bit, I am considering adding a new index. Initially I thought I was knowledgeable enough to add an adequate index, but I am starting to second-guess myself.

### Question

Which of the following index definitions would (possibly) be an adequate solution?

#### 1. Index without INCLUDE

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDXNew] ON [schema_owner].[object1]
(
    [deleted] ASC,
    [feld16] ASC,
    [zahl4] ASC,
    [feld12] ASC,
    [feld19] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = ON, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
```

#### 2. Index with INCLUDE

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDXNew] ON [schema_owner].[object1]
(
    [feld16] ASC,
    [zahl4] ASC,
    [feld12] ASC,
    [feld19] ASC
)
INCLUDE 
(
    [deleted] ASC
)
WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = ON, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
```

#### 3. Index with INCLUDE, but the other way round

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDXNew] ON [schema_owner].[object1]
(
    [deleted] ASC
)
INCLUDE(
    [feld12],
    [zahl4],
    [feld16],
    [feld19]
) 
WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
```

### My Initial Thoughts

.. were to go with the first index definition and include all the columns. On reading up on the `INCLUDE` part of the index creation I thought of creating the second index. I then thought: *Why not add a filter to the index like `deleted = 0 or deleted IS NULL`* and then started second guessing my knowledge about indexes.

### Additional Information

There are some trace flags running on the SQL Server 2016 instance. Some were recommended to us by Microsoft PFE during a PTOC.

```
<TraceFlag Value="2335" Scope="Global" /> -- Assume fixed amount of memory
<TraceFlag Value="2371" Scope="Global" /> -- Updates statistics in linear mode
<TraceFlag Value="4199" Scope="Global" /> -- Enable QO fixes
```

And the CE is currently set to run in backwards compatibility mode:

```
CardinalityEstimationModelVersion="70"
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't just set those 10 rows where Deleted is `NULL` to have Deleted as `0` and enforce it as `NOT NULL` going forward? Is there any distinction between the two cases or possibility of future NULL being added?

Comment: Old data and it's tax relevant and that comes with a 10 year minimum **"Dont' Modify"** tag attached.

Comment: Seems like it was a one-off (adhoc) query. Couldn't grab an actual plan. The query would run for 4 hours.

Answer (score 6):

If you specifically want to optimise for getting these results quickly then one method would be an indexed view.

With a view definition of

```
SELECT feld16,
       zahl4,
       feld12,
       feld19,
       COUNT_big(*) AS [count]
FROM   object1
WHERE  ( deleted = 0
          OR deleted IS NULL )
GROUP  BY feld16,
          zahl4,
          feld12,
          feld19
```

And a unique clustered index created on `feld16, zahl4, feld12, feld19` then a `SELECT` against that view (potentially with `NOEXPAND` hint dependent on SQL Server edition) would likely be the fastest way of getting this data as it will all be pre-calculated in advance.

I'd be reluctant to use an indexed view for this case though as it still has nearly as many rows as the original table.

I would go for your index 1 and hope to see two seeks (for `deleted = 0` and `deleted is null`) merge unioned together on the other four columns and then fed into a stream aggregate to remove the duplicates without any sorting or hashing (or ideally with the duplicate removal before the merge).

The reason why the merge union and stream aggregate(s) would be possible is that both the seeks will return rows in `[feld16] ASC, [zahl4] ASC, [feld12] ASC, [feld19] ASC` order.

If you don't get the desired execution plan it may need a query rewrite to

```
SELECT feld16,
       zahl4,
       feld12,
       feld19
FROM   object1
WHERE  ( deleted = 0 )
UNION
SELECT feld16,
       zahl4,
       feld12,
       feld19
FROM   object1
WHERE  ( deleted IS NULL )
```

Comment: I tested with row counts and distribution from the question and the query rewrite is needed for the stream aggregate. Interestingly, the [legacy CE plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=B1_VzD3Fs) uses a merge union but the [current (160) CE plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ByWjGP3Yj) uses a merge concatenation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The view solution is currently out-of-scope as the system is using generated SQL Statements (Kinda ORM-like). Will see what happens.

Comment: I forgot to add the 10 NULL deleted rows in my test data. Once I did, the [legacy](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=r1mzPw3Fi) and [new CE](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rJ-9Dv3Ki) plans are the same, both using merge concat. Amazing how such a small difference can change the plan shape.

Comment: @JohnK.N., even if the ORM doesn't reference the indexed view, the optimizer might consider it depending on your edition. But I agree with Martin that it's probably not worth it in this case.

Comment: Using the index 1 (non-clustered) results in one **index seek** in the [actual execution plan for a TOP 2000 query](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=By1Gzdb5s) and the same for the [estimated execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rJgzVO-cs) for the whole 64 million records .

Answer (score -4):

A filtered index with the 4 column needed, should avoid the "concatenation", the "key Lookup" and the "sort" steps shown in the Plan, improving query performance.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERE INDEX CoverTest1 ON [Schema_owner].[object1]
( feld12, zahl4, feld16, feld19 )
WHERE ISNULL(deleted, 0) = 0
```

I tested something similar (just 10Mln rows, different statistics, ...) comparing  multiple indexes and the one above made the best change in terms of time and resources.

Comment: Can you add some specific details of your tests rather than just asserting that you did some tests and this was the best? What was the setup? What were the results? Did you make any changes to the query? I'd be surprised if it matched `(deleted = 0 or deleted IS NULL)` to that filtered index

Comment: In fact that isn't even a valid filtered index definition "Incorrect WHERE clause for filtered index 'CoverTest1' on table 'object1'."

Comment: sorry @MartinSmith, you are right: my answer was superficial.
I just meant that in my test environment with my test data, a filtered index had given me better results.
I promise that as soon as I get back to the office I will edit the answer by adding all the available details.
tnks for your comment.